# Broken pipes with Minecraft multiplayer servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Okay, so I've looked over a ton of sites for the same issue I'm having, and the only solution I've found to my error was sticking with 1.7.x.

Basically, about 40 percent of the time when I connect to servers it will give me one of three errors:

2. `Connection lost: timed out.`
3. `Connection lost: disconnected.`
4. `Connection lost: Error while write (...) Broken pipe.`

It's not like I can just connect again to the server afterwards: I have to restart Minecraft to connect.
Also, I can usually connect to main lobbies of servers, but when I click on a minigame it'll give me the error.

I'm using Oracle Java 8 on Ubuntu 15.10, but I've also tried using OpenJDK 7 and 8. I had long suspected my connection was at fault, but I don't have the same issue with my two computers with Debian7.

Does anyone have any ideas on what could be wrong or how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a not-well known error, which I find occurs mostly when Minecraft 1.9 is downloading custom stuff (texture packs, etc). The only way of solving this is to restart the game.

Comment: Well, it only happens about once a month in 1.9. The only time it's really annoying is 1.8.9, where it happens a ton. Additionally, it seems to happen _far_ less in 1.8.8 as well.
Very strange.

Comment: Haha, yeah. Just realized.